# ReactJS - Spread operator syntax + hooks function error

Tags: reactjs, state, spread-syntax, use-state

I am new to Web development and in that uncomfortable zone of not knowing which words to use when doing a web search. I haven't learned much about classes, as my teacher told us to avoid using it, and unfortunately the only answers I find connect to classes.
I am trying to apply a sort function to a data table, and only in the very beginning of my attempt, but struggling with 2 things :

```
import CountryCases from "../Components/CountryCases";
import NewsColumn from "../Components/NewsColumn";
import { Cases } from "../State/use-backend";

const HomeView = () => {
  const { data } = Cases(); // data is an object with 200 arrays //
  const stats = {...data};
  const { sort, setSort } = useState([]);

  const sortBy = key => {
    setSort(stats);
    console.log(sort);
  };

  return (
    <div className="home-view__container">
      <CountryCases stats={stats} sortBy={sortBy} />
      <NewsColumn />
    </div>
  );
};

export default HomeView;
```

1. Assigning the API object to a const in my component. (I am using a spread iterator, which works, but doesn't work when I use it in a hook - for example - 'useState({...data})'. When I don't use a spread operator, it shows 'undefined'. So now I am creating my 'sort, setSort' separately, but assigning my 'stats' object as a value returns undefined too. Can someone please explain how this data communication works?
2. When my 'sortBy' function is fired, I get an error saying "*setSort* is not a function". It's a hook within a function, so I am very confused by this??

Obviously I don't speak *code* that well yet, hope you can understand!

Comment: The 2nd question is answered, however I suspect `Cases()` return a promise instead of a plain object. You probably wanna check `console.log(Cases())` to see if it says `Promise { something }`.

Comment: It returns  -  function Cases() {}
<constructor>: "Function" When I console log 'stats' the object is shown, and if I use a spread operator on stats, my setSort accepts the whole object. I will go read about promises to understand that better, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You call to useState is wrong, it is a tuple, not an object that is returned:

```
const [ sort, setSort ] = useState([]);
```

You can read more about hooks here: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html

And regarding your data issue: `data` is initially undefined, it gets populated when the fetching is done so you cannot use it as initial value for useState.

Comment: Thank you, what a dunce error. *facepalm* So in this case is it best practice to create an extra state for my sorting function? ie [sort, setSort] and only assign a value within the sortBy function?

Answer (score 0):

its just a typo

```js
const [sort, setSort] = useState([]);  // use [ ] not { }
```

Comment: *facepalm*  Thank you!

Comment: sure no problem @OhGee don't forget to accept my answer